# Java real time facial recognition library

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection, javacv

I'm eagerly on the search for a library (that is Java based or has Java bindings), that can perform real time facial recognition:

- It should be able to run at 30 frames per second (25 FPS is also permissible).
- It should be able to detect a given face and be
  able to detect it in a large crowd of people.

I am willing to pay for the library, but I would prefer if it were free or open source. I would also really appreciate some references to tutorials on this topic/library.

PS: I have done some research (have not quite found what I'm looking for), but I would still love to hear what the Stack Overflow community has to say.

Comment: Maybe you can post as an answer what you have found

Comment: I believe your requirements are well beyond the current state-of-the-art for such things.

Comment: @antlersoft When you say "beyond the current state-of-the-art", are you referring to a specific requirement, or all of them in general?

Comment: @JasonSperske I can update my question with some content that I have found on the web.

Comment: Yes please do update, this sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same opinion as @antlersoft (see question's comments).

A quick search brings me to [this paper](http://eprints.qut.edu.au/57212/): «*Efficient Real-Time Face Detection For High Resolution Surveillance Applications*» which seems currently near the top of the state of the art in the domain (published in 2012), and close to your request.

The authors propose a method that runs faster than previous algorithms, 42ms per image, which corresponds to a frame rate of approximatively 24 images/second. As the Figure 2 shows, the algorithm is pretty complex.

Sadly we are still in the field of face **detection** and not face **recognition**, which is even more difficult and computationally intensive.

So I think it will be hard to find a library that already offers an algorithm that fulfill your needs. If you still want to make that, I'm afraid the only solution will be to implement your own algorithm based on research paper, and that would be difficult. In this case the choice of the *Computer Vision* library must be based on performances, to hope reaching at the end the 30 FPS.